# Beanstalk git aws.push fatal: repository http://..... not found

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I keep getting an error when trying:

```
git aws.push
```

Eventually I get it working by running `AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.bat` or so it seems like this is what solves it.

The original error is something like this:

> Pushing to environment: my-env
>   fatal: repository 'https://FJEOAKFP****:324fafaefr3234*****@git.elasticbeanstalk.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/1234/commitid/49498480914984984984fefe6595/environment/454845451548461654ef/' not found

Comment: sounds like something is wrong with the installation. I'd start fresh, and this time using EB CLI v3

Comment: It's very strange because it seems to go on and off. If I re run It again after the error it sometimes work. I will try to look how to re init thanks

Comment: I have the same error, it happen very often when I push in short intervals, might amazon has limits in Elastic Beanstalk